# Java: Commons-Collections generics: How to get custom transformer to work

Tags: java, generics, transformer-model, apache-commons-collection

Hi i am using commons collections generics 4.01.

I have a dto object.

```
Class PricingDto {
   private Double tax;
   private Double price;
   private Double tip;

   // getters and setters
}
```

i have a list of `List<PricingDto> pricingDtos = this.pricingService.getAllPricings();`

than i have a private static class.

```
import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;
import org.apache.commons.collections15.list.TransformedList;

class TotalServiceImpl implements TotalService {
    public static final PricingDtoTransformer PRICING_DTO_TRANSFORMER =
        new PricingDtoTransformer();
    private static class PricingDtoTransformer
        implements Transformer<PricingDto, Double> {
        public PricingDtoTransformer() {}

        @Override
        public Double transform(final PricingDto pricingDto) {
            return pricingDto.getTax()
                     + pricingDto.getPrice()
                     + pricingDto.getTips();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Double> getListDouble(final List<PricingDto> pricingDtos) {
        final List<Double> totalList = 
            TransformedList.decorate(pricingDtos, PRICING_DTO_TRANSFORMER);
            for (Double d : totalList) {
                // print them. 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is i get class cast exception, because each item in totalList is a PricingDto and not Double.

2.) What did i do wrong. Whats the correct way to implement custom transformer for generics commons-collections.

Comment: what must `getListDouble` actually do? It returns a `List<Double>` but I can't understand what `listDouble` actually mean....what must it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming the collections in place seems like an awful hack to me. I'd suggest using [Google Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) instead. It's [`Lists.transform(List,Function)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List%2C%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) returns a view that is backed by the original List and a mapping function, so you're not actually changing anything.

Here's what your code would look like:

```
class TotalServiceImpl implements TotalService{

    private static final Function<PricingDto, Double> PRICING_DTO_TRANSFORMER =
        new PricingDtoTransformer();

    private static class PricingDtoTransformer implements
        Function<PricingDto, Double>{

        public PricingDtoTransformer(){
        }

        @Override
        public Double apply(final PricingDto pricingDto){
            return pricingDto.getTax() + pricingDto.getPrice()
                + pricingDto.getTips();
        }
    }

    public List<Double> getListDouble(final List<PricingDto> pricingDtos){
        final List<Double> totalList =
            Lists.transform(pricingDtos, PRICING_DTO_TRANSFORMER);
        for(final Double d : totalList){
            // print them.
        }
        return totalList;
    }

}
```

Commons-Collections might also have a similar mechanism, but I couldn't find it at first glance.

Comment: I found my answer. I had to use CollectionUtils.collect(pricingDtos, PricingDtoTransformer) to make things work.

Comment: Ah, yes. That sounds a lot better

Answer (score 6):

The [javadocs](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/list/TransformedList.html) clearly state that:

> If there are any elements already in
>   the list being decorated, they are NOT
>   transformed.

Try the following instead:

```
CollectionUtils.transform(pricingDtos, PRICING_DTO_TRANSFORMER);
```

which will transform the collection by applying the Transformer to each element.

Comment: CollectionUtils.transform won't work cause i am transforming an object of type PricingDto to Double. 

After doing the transformation. When i do for (Double totalPrice : resultTotals) { .... } i get class cast exception saying the object inside are PricingDto and not Double.